# php is user session/cookie valid redirect error

Tags: php, session

The following code should check if a valid session exists or a valid cookie and if so `include_once file A.php` if not `include_once login.php`.

So far the `login.php` and `logout.php` are executing correctly (session/cookie) are being created and destroyed but the following code is still not displaying the proper content.

As this code stands I am seeing the `login.php` regardless of valid session or cookie.

Any help would be great. Thank you.

```
<?php
include_once '../accounts/dbc.php'; 

if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && isset($_SESSION['user_name']) ) 
{
    include_once 'A.php';
}
else if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
    /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

    $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
    $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
    // coookie expiry
    if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

        include_once '../login.php';
        }
/* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.       
/* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

     if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
          session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

          $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
        /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */  
          list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

          $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
          $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

          include_once 'A.php';
       } 
       else {
          include_once '../login.php';
       }

  } else {
  include_once '../login.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `COOKIE_TIME_OUT` and `$ctime`? Can you print both of those?

Comment: @Tushar when you say print you mean .... (sr im a bit out of my depth here)

Comment: @Tushar if you want I have a stacksoverflow chat open. No need to fill up this area.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/27461/discussion-between-aventus-and-webmaster-alex-l

Comment: Just checking.. you do have a `session_start()` somewhere at the top, right?

Comment: if you want to join the chat room @Cumbo your more then welcome to. At this time the (validuser.inc.php) code may be correct and the errors I am running into are caused by the login.php not setting the session or cookie

Comment: @Tushar iv narrowed down the problem to a small section of code in the login.php file. Iv pasted the code into the chat room. When you have a moment. Thank you.

Comment: it took two 13hr days and some help but after the 3rd rewrite things seems to be working with only one small server causation error that I just will have to live with. This question can be closed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it took two 13hr days and some help but after the 3rd rewrite things seems to be working with only one small server causation error that I just will have to live with. This question can be closed. Thank you.